# How do you track custom events from Azure WebJobs in Application Insights?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

I have an Azure WebJobs (v2.2.0) project that I would like to monitor with Application Insights (AI), and there are events that I would like to be able to track. In a normal web app that is configured to use AI you can just use this:

```
TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient();
tc.TrackEvent("EventName");
```

However this seems not to work in the context of a WebJob! I have configured my WebJob project as per the instructions on the [WebJob SDK repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Application-Insights-Integration) which ends up looking like this:

#### Program

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebJobs
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main()
    {
      JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
      config.UseTimers();

      using (LoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory())
      {
        string key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["webjob-instrumentation-key"];
        loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(key, null);
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        config.LoggerFactory = loggerFactory;
        config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Off;

        if (config.IsDevelopment)                
          config.UseDevelopmentSettings();                

        JobHost host = new JobHost(config);

        host.RunAndBlock();
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

#### Functions

This is just a test function that will run every minute for half an hour.

```
using Core.Telemetry;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebJobs.Functions
{
  public class TestFunctions
  {
    public void TelemetryTest([TimerTrigger(typeof(Schedule))] TimerInfo timer)
    {
      TelemetryClient tc = new TelemetryClient();
      tc.TrackEvent("TelemetryTestEvent");
    }

    // schedule that will run every minute
    public class Schedule : DailySchedule
    {
        private static readonly string[] times =
        {
          "12:01","12:02","12:03","12:04","12:05","12:06","12:07","12:08","12:09","12:10",
          "12:11","12:12","12:13","12:14","12:15","12:16","12:17","12:18","12:19","12:20",
          "12:21","12:22","12:23","12:24","12:25","12:26","12:27","12:28","12:29","12:30"
        };

        public Schedule() : base(times) { }
    }
  }
}
```

This seems to partially work in that I can see some telemetry in AI but not the custom events. For example I can see a **Request** show up each time `TestFunctions.TelemetryTest()` runs and various **Trace**s during the initialisation of the WebJob.

I have probably not configured something properly or am not getting the `TelemetryClient` in the correct manner, but I cannot find any documentation on tracking custom events in WebJobs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try setting the instrumentationkey explicit: `tc.Context.InstrumentationKey = "<your_key>";`

Comment: I misread your comment and set `tc.InstrumentationKey = "<you_key>";` instead and that works! I doubt that this is the intended way to do it though so maybe I will raise an issue on the github repo. If you add this as an answer I will accept it seeing as it solved my problem, Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the instrumentationkey explicit:

```
tc.Context.InstrumentationKey = "<your_key>";
```

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#custom-telemetry-in-c-functions) you should be able to get the key using

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(
            "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)
```

if you have set up application insights integration.